# Content of WordPress site is not being loaded from CloudFront

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, amazon-cloudfront

We have configure our WordPress website with AWS CloudFront. We used w3-total-cache plugin to configure CDN for CloudFront. All the static content has been already cached in CloudFront but somehow that content is not getting served from CloudFront.

We have another issue with browser caching for which tried changing Max TTL, Min TTL and default TTL in CloudFront. We also tried changing some values in .htaccess for expiration policy but in vain. Let me know if you need to check what changes I made in my .htaccess file for expiration policy.

We were analyzing website performance in gtmetrix.com, and it is saying that remove redirect chain. Please find screenshot below and help me to figure out the problem.

[image]

[image]

Find the CloudFront configuration

[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: How do you know the content isn't being served from CloudFront? Is Wordpress generating the URLs correctly to point at CloudFront? Re your second question, if CloudFront isn't in place what headers are being set by Wordpress regarding caching? Please edit your question with further information, don't try and cram it into a comment to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to invalidate all the cloudfront content and have it read from your web server again. If cloudfront received a 302 redirect at the time of the request, it would cache that redirect and serve it instead of the real page content. The default expiry of cloudfront is very very long, for most uses it makes sense to shorten it to 3 hours or so